# How to deal with extra hash in route? (AngularJS 1.5 + new/component router)

Tags: angularjs, thinktecture-ident-server, angular-new-router, identityserver2, ngcomponentrouter

We're attempting to build an app using Angular 1.5 with the new component router bits. We've run into a bit of an edge case and we're wondering if there's any way around it.

### The Key Players

- **[IdentityServer v2](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer2)**: our client uses this for OAuth currently. It causes a part of this problem. It's legacy, and we don't have control over its usage.
- **AngularJS 1.5** as our front-end framework.
- **The new angular router**, called ngComponentRouter now I believe? We figured this style would help us bridge between Angular v1.5 and Angular v2, and it was easy enough to port.
- **[oauth-ng](http://angularjs-oauth.github.io/oauth-ng/)** as a wrapper for our OAuth implicit flow..
- **Older browsers**: In the sense that we have to support IE9+, meaning we can't use Angular's HTML5 mode.

### The Goal

We'd like to take a URL such as `http://mysite/#!/auth/#auth_token=xyz123` (structure not under our control, e.g. can't remove second hash) and:

- Get it into an actual auth controller
- Have the auth_token value available, either through parameters or directly through `$location`. (it currently is scrubbed before it ever gets to the controller).

### Background / Problem

Our client has a central login system where they're using IdentityServer v2. As far as I understand, when we request a token from IdSrv v2, it responds by appending `#auth_token=xyz123` to your redirect URL. It was written back when it thought you'd have `my.com/login.html`, thus resulting in `login.html#auth_token=xyz123`.

With an Angular app that uses a hash already, though, it becomes a problem, as the URL ends up along the lines of `mysite.com/#/auth#auth_token=xyz123`.

This, as you might expect, makes Angular angry. We have yet be able to find a way to get this to work under the component router.

### How it Would Work With the Older Routers

Per the [oauth-ng docs](http://angularjs-oauth.github.io/oauth-ng/#html5), if we were using the older router without html5 enabled, we'd do something like the following:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
      template: '',
      controller: function ($location, AccessToken) {
        var hash = $location.path().substr(1);
        AccessToken.setTokenFromString(hash);
        $location.path('/');
        $location.replace();
      }
    })
```

### What We've Tried

- **Defining a component route in a similar way.** This didn't work, because `/access_token=:accessToken` contains an `=`, which doesn't appear to be allowed by component router.
- **Seeing if we can get IdentityServer v2 to change the format of the response**. It doesn't seem like it's possible; the response seems to be hard-coded to `[URL we define]#auth_token=xyz123`.
- Faking out the URL using other hashes, etc. Generally wound up with bad / inconsistent behavior.

### What We Think our Options Are

- **Use a catch-all / not found controller**. If we let the route fall all the way through to `/**`, we can retrieve the token value from `$location`. That's sort of gross though; we'd like to avoid it.
- **Find a way to get the full URL into the controller**. We can capture the route and put it through to a controller, but the URL isn't available at that point.
- Go back to using the older router or ui-router (which we'd like not to do at this point).

Anything that could point us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be off topic but have you guys tried ui-router?

Comment: @adeel_s we chose the new component router over ui-router for this process for other reasons related to this project, so unfortunately that's not a possibility at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on this: in the end, we decided that this was a strange enough edge-case that it warranted returning to `ui-router`.

While we think the component router makes the most sense, the deciding factor here is that, unfortunately, *we don't have 100% control over our routes.* The route constraint included the edge case that component-router did not seem capable of handling at the current time.

For those who are working with older oauth server systems, I hope this will serve as a warning / some background as you're making your choice of router.

Hopefully ngComponentRouter will better support this edge case in the future, though I wouldn't blame them for leaving it out.